# Quicksort on a sorted array disturb by uniform noise

Tags: algorithm, math, quicksort

This is a homework problem I've recieved and I'm unsure on how to solve (and there's no solution provided). The problem is as follows:

You are provided as input an array A of n keys that has been generated by the equation:

A[i] = i + u

where u is random noise which is uniform between [-k, k], where k << n. The problem is to implement quicksort algorithm which sorts this array, and has a worst case performance of O(nlogn) (and so avoids the worst case O(n^2) performance).

I'm thinking the key is to choose a partition function which guarantees the pivot we choose is not the smallest or greatest element to avoid the worst case O(n^2) performance, however I'm not sure how to go about writing such a partition function.

Comment: What about just choosing the pivot in the middle of the array?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community - the array is nearly sorted A[i] ~= i, with a relatively small amount of noise (i+u), (k << n). Using middle value or median of 3 with middle value would be good enough. It the noise results in duplicate values, then Hoare partition scheme would be better than Lomuto partition scheme.